# Zend_Auth_Http with PHP as CGI

Tags: zend-framework, http-authentication

Here's another question from me:

I've played around with Zend_Auth_Http and everything seems to be working fine when it's run on a server where PHP is run as an apache module. When PHP is run as a CGI script it's a whole different story, since this doesn't support HTTP authorisation. I have googled a bit and found [this post](http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/http-auth-php-cgi.html) which describes a workaround for this problem. This all works but ideally I would like to use Zend_Auth_Http to do most of the work for me in my Zend Framework application. Is there a way to do this?

Here are some details about my hosting package (1&1):

- PHP Version 5.2.17
- Server API: CGI/FastCGI

I hope somebody can help here and what I want to do isn't impossible.

Thanks very much in advance and feel free to ask questions if I haven't given you enough info!

Simon

Comment: Have you tried just adding the rewrite to htaccess? Comments here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.adapter.http.html suggest it works

Answer (score 0):

to expand on Ashley's comment, this comment in the reference for [Zend_Auth_Http_Adpter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.adapter.http.html) suggest a possible work around by adding an .htaccess rule.

> Posted by: Jean-Benoît Murat on: 2011-01-25 10:57:17 ⁋ My Basic http
>   authentication works on fast cgi/ cgi (Apache/Zend Server)
>
> by adding  RewriteRule .* -
>   [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
>
> in .htaccess file

Comment: Yes, I have tried that - sorry, I should've mentioned that. The problem is that I can see that the server now passes the authorisation details, but for some reason, zend_Auth still doesn't accept it.